# How do I install widgets in Unity?

Tags: unity

Where can I find a way to install this widget on my Ubuntu PC?

[image: go on this link to see the widget I am looking for]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for [Conky](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky).

To install it on your Ubuntu, do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

To remove conky manager:

```
sudo apt-get remove conky-manager
```

There are plenty of [Conky themes](https://www.google.com/search?q=conky%20themes&espv=2&biw=1331&bih=659&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=Xy5RVbKpLOXIsQSnyoHQDg&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QsAQ) all over the web. You may find one to fit your needs.

**UPDATE**:

As stated by [Nahuel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622513/how-do-i-install-widgets-in-unity/622528#comment1133781_622528), You no longer need to add the PPA.

So to install conky:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install conky
```

To remove:

```
sudo apt-get remove conky
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for ,thanks alot sir

Comment: You're welcome, my friend.

Comment: You no longer need to add the PPA :) `sudo apt-get install conky`

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run:

```
sudo apt-get install screenlets
```

Then run `screenlets` when finished. Choose your wigdet.

Comment: Just as a side note, screenlets is no longer updated, and is not supported on 16.04+.